# Make a local connection appear as external

Tags: networking

I have to test the connectivity to a server part of a program I've written. I have to ensure that anyone can connect to the server from anywhere (not just from the local network).

Since both my computer and the server are on a local network, is there any way I can initiate connection from my computer, but convince the router it's coming from the outside of the network, forcing the connection through all the filters on the router and the server to make sure it doesn't get blocked.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very unlikely you need to test this wrt. to your program. Unless you totally screwed up your program by doing intentionally really unusual things, it should just work, no matter where you connect from.

You may have to configure port forwarding on your router, though, so it's really the router you need to test.

The simplest way to force a connection from outside is to use a VPN, either from a second computer inside your network, or from a network namespace (linux) or some kind of virtual machine.